# OpenFileDialog in SilverLight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding

I have download the code for OpenFileDialog (File Upload function) from Silverlight tutorials website. I am creating a silverlight application using ESRI API and I would like to incorporate the file upload functionality in to it. I have replicated the exact code in to my application there are no errors when I run it, but for some reason my application dosen't execute this line of code "c.OpenWriteAsync(Ub.Uri)"

Edit 2: I notice another thing when I upgraded the general handler (receiver.ashx) which I downloaded it has the following as first line while my generic handler doesn't

<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="receiver" %>
I dont know why my code dosent trigger it :(

Here is my Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Browser;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;


namespace DataTool
{
  public partial class MainPage : UserControl
  {
  public MainPage()
  {
  InitializeComponent();
  Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
  }

  void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
   // HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("SilverlightLearn", this);
  }

  [ScriptableMember]
  private void btnService_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
  }

  private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
  OpenFileDialog Dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
  Dialog.Multiselect = false;
  Dialog.Filter = "All Files|*.*";

  bool? SelFil = Dialog.ShowDialog();

  if (SelFil != null && SelFil == true)
  {
  string selectedfilename = Dialog.File.Name;
  UploadFile(selectedfilename, Dialog.File.OpenRead());

  }
  else
  {
  //do something else
  }
  }
  private void StoreIso(string fileName, Stream data)
  {

  }

  private void UploadFile(string fileName, System.IO.Stream data)
  {
   // WebClient Wbc = new WebClient();
  UriBuilder Ub = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:63461/DataTool/datareceiver.ashx");
  Ub.Query = string.Format("filename={0}", fileName);

  WebClient c = new WebClient();
  c.OpenWriteCompleted += (sender, e) =>
  {
  PushData(data, e.Result);
  e.Result.Close();
  data.Close();
  };
  c.OpenWriteAsync(Ub.Uri);
  }
  private void PushData(Stream input, Stream output)
  {

  byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
  int bytesRead;

  while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
  {
  output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
  }

  }

  }
}
```

Here is my datareceiver.ashx code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

namespace DataTool.Web
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Summary description for datareceiver
  /// </summary>
  public class datareceiver : IHttpHandler
  {

  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
  {
  string filename = context.Request.QueryString["filename"].ToString();

  using (FileStream fs = File.Create(context.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + filename)))
  {
  SaveFile(context.Request.InputStream, fs);
  }

  }
  public void SaveFile(Stream st, FileStream fs)
  {
  byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
  int bytesRead;

  while ((bytesRead = st.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
  {
  fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
  }
  }

  public bool IsReusable
  {
  get
  {
  return false;
  }
  }
  }
}
```

I have gone through the downloaded sample code  and my code STEP BY STEP and found that my code dosent execute the OpenWriteAsync statement. The downloaded code was in .net 3.5 or 3.0 framework and I upgraded it to 4.0.

EDIT:
Please find a sample here https://rapidshare.com/files/459667631/Testing.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple , check following code

```
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
dlg.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt";
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = dlg.SelectedFile.OpenText())

        // Store file content in 'text' variable
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}


C# Example 2: Copy files to the application's isolated storage.  
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
...

OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
dlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
dlg.EnableMultipleSelection = true;
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    // Save all selected files into application's isolated storage
    IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    foreach (FileDialogFileInfo file in dlg.SelectedFiles) {
        using (Stream fileStream = file.OpenRead()) {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream =
                new IsolatedStorageFileStream(file.Name, FileMode.Create, iso)) {

                // Read and write the data block by block until finish
                while(true) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[100001];
                    int count = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (count > 0) {
                        isoStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
         }
    }
}
```